# Error: No chunks found for a file with Mongo gridFS

Tags: mongodb, meteor, gridfs, modulus, modulus.io

An error has crashed my application server and I can't seem to figure out what could be causing the issue. My application is built with Meteor and hosted on modulus.io. Here are my application logs:

```
Error: no chunks found for file, possibly corrupt
    at /mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js:817:20
    at /mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js:594:7
    at /mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:758:35
    at Cursor.close (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:989:5)
    at Cursor.nextObject (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:758:17)
    at commandHandler (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:727:14)
    at /mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1916:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:448:41)
    at /mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:481:18
    at [object Object].MongoReply.parseBody (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
[2015-03-29T22:05:57.573Z] Application CRASH detected. Exit code 8.
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is a [mongo bug with gridfs](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-168) (has been fixed)

> Writing two or more different files concurrently from different node
>   processes using the GridStore.writeFile command results in some files
>   not being correctly written (ending up with a number of corrupt files
>   in the gridstore). Ending up with corrupt files even with all
>   writeFile calls being successfull and no indication of error.
>   writeFile occasionally fails with error "chunks out of order", but
>   this happens very rarely (something like 1 failed writeFile for 100
>   corrupt files or more).

Based on the comments with in a discussion, the problem will be fixed if you will update mongo (the gridfs files should be removed, as they are corrupt).

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: no chunks found for file, possibly corrupt
at /home/developer/rundir/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js:808:20
at /home/developer/rundir/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js:586:5
at /home/developer/rundir/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/query.js:164:5
at /home/developer/rundir/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:778:35
```

I had a similar occurance, but it ended up the file sought in a GFS read stream had actually been deleted - so in my case it wasn't corrupt, but gone! Above is a log from when that happened.

Comment: Well, you could wrap this in an 'exists' check easily enough.